# How to remove the big blank space in "str" tag in the XML response generated by Apache Solr ?

Tags: xml, solr, lucene

I used to upload and index Word documents using the following url..

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1 -Dtype=application/word -jar post.jar document_name.doc
```

When I query the Solr Index it returns XML as ..

```
  http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=microfost&wt=xml&indent=true
```

The Response was :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="indent">true</str>
<str name="q">microfost</str>
<str name="_">1389196238897</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">1</str>
<date name="last_modified">1601-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
<str name="author">fazlan </str>
<str name="author_s">fazlan </str>
<arr name="content_type">
<str>application/msword</str>
</arr>
<arr name="content">

<str>  <-- problemtic tag with blank space -->

























This is a MSWord document. Microfost.

</str>
</arr>
<long name="_version_">1456677821213573120</long></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

Now my problem is , the `<str>` tag marked as  <-- problemtic tag -->  under `<arr name="content" >` always return this `<str>` with large number of blank space followed by content .. How to get rid off this ..

(I know to remove using java / jquery ..but i want to find solution form the xml level that done without any post processing )

.

Answer (score 1):

Tika is extracting the text from the doc documents and it does not modify such content. The values returned by solr are the stored ones, so you have to modify such contents before they are indexed.

You could use an [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) to take the 'content' field, and trim it, and them let it go through. I suspect that would work, as the updateprocessor would kick in after the extraction has happened.